# How to only allow one check box to be selected of iframe window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Below is my javascript code

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('pltc');
iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<input type="checkbox" name="tc0">Yes<input type="checkbox" name="tc0">N0<br/><br/><br/><br/><input type="checkbox" name="tc1">Yes<input type="checkbox" name="tc1">No ');
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

//Near checkboxes
$('#pltc input[name="tc0"]').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

I have a iframe tag with id="plc" in my html code and include above js code.
What I want is to make only one checkbox can be selected at the same time.

But not working.

Comment: Multiple options but only one at a time is allowed? -> use radio buttons

Comment: @aBloomer i dont get totally your problem, the iframe content is something you set by JS or the code above is just a example to reproduce same situation?

Comment: @craifaro above code is my js code. I create two checkbox with same name attribute and what i want is when i click on one of them, another one is unblock.

Comment: @aBloomer i asked you that because when i run your code, in the iframe content i only can see the html-text but the tags checkboxes,...

Comment: If you only want one to be selected, why are you using checkboxes in the first place? That's what radio buttons are for.

Comment: @aBloomer what i sent you suit your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think i know your problem. As you are trying to add code in an Iframe, the document ready of your main page doesn't affect to him, so you have to add manually all your script code into the file directly.
I made it work, but is really hard to read and not very scalable, I dont know why you need to do something like that but if you could find another way but use Iframe will save some future problems. Anyway here is the code:

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = 'function checkTypeTc0(type) {       if(type == "no" && document.getElementById("idTc0Yes").checked) {       document.getElementById("idTc0Yes").checked=false;  } else if(type == "yes" && document.getElementById("idTc0No").checked) {    document.getElementById("idTc0No").checked=false;   }}';
```

iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);

Here the HTML code i had to add some id's as far in the JS code we cant use JQuery notation

```
var text  = '<input id="idTc0Yes" type="checkbox" name="tc0" onclick=checkTypeTc0("yes")>Yes<input id="idTc0No" type="checkbox" name="tc0" onclick=checkTypeTc0("no")>N0<br/><br/><br/><br/><input type="checkbox" name="tc1">Yes<input type="checkbox" name="tc1">No <button id="ruben">eo</button>';  
var doc = document.getElementById('pltc').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(text);
doc.close();
```

Let me know if this suit your problem